# Avoid Duplicate Sub Categories to get inserted into database

Tags: php

I am saving main categories, sub categories and tertiary level categories in database. I am trying to restrict duplicate categories entry into database.
I can restrict Duplicate Main Categories to get inserted into database.
But for Sub Categories, i am again trying to restrict duplicate entry of sub categories against the main category, but it is not working. Duplicate Sub categories are getting inserted

Database Image [image]

```
<form class="theme-form theme-form-2 mega-form" method="post" action="query_create_scat.php">
 <div class="mb-4 row align-items-center">
 <label class="form-label-title col-sm-3 mb-0">Select Main Category</label>
  <div class="col-sm-9">
      <select class="form-control" name="main_cat_id" required >
         <option value="">Select Category</option>
         <?php
         $SelectmainCat = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM main_cat");
         while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($SelectmainCat)){
         ?>
        <option value="<?= $row['id']; ?>"><?= $row['main_cat']; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="mb-4 row align-items-center">
    <label class="form-label-title col-sm-3 mb-0">Sub Category Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
    <input class="form-control" name="sub_cat_name" type="text" placeholder="Sub Category Name">
    </div>
</div>

<button type="submit" name="create_scats" class="btn btn-info font-medium rounded-pill px-4">Create Sub Category</button>
</form>

<?php
include "include/config.php";

if (isset($_POST['create_scats'])) {
    $main_cat_id = $_POST['main_cat_id'];
    $sub_cat_name = $_POST['sub_cat_name'];

    $checkQuery = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM sub_cat WHERE main_cat_id = '$main_cat_id' AND sub_cat_name = '$sub_cat_name'");
    $existingSubCategory = mysqli_fetch_assoc($checkQuery);

    if ($existingSubCategory) {
 
        $_SESSION['scaterror'] = "<h4 style='color:#ed2324; align:center'>Sub Category already exists for the selected Main Category.</h4>";
        header('Location: add-sub-category.php');
        exit;
    } else {
 
        $insertQuery = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO sub_cat (main_cat_id, sub_cat_name) VALUES ('$main_cat_id', '$sub_cat_name')") or die(mysqli_error($con));

        if ($insertQuery) {
            $_SESSION['scatsuccess'] = "<h4 style='color:#00cc00; align:center'>Sub Category is created successfully.</h4>";
            header('Location: add-sub-category.php');
            exit;
        } else {
            echo 'Something Went Wrong. Please Try Again!';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you give some examples of inserted subcategories from your snapshot?

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32391315)

Comment: It is a very bad idea to use `die(mysqli_error($$conn));` in your code, because it could potentially leak sensitive information. See this post for more explanation: [mysqli or die, does it have to die?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15320411/1839439)

Comment: nice_dev, it is already showing in the database screenshot